# Php class to pharse XML

Tags: php, xml

I am writing a simple class to read XML file and store its elements inside separate variables. As i finished writting my class and start testing it I noticed that it does not return anything..?

My php code:

> ```
> <?php
> ```
>
> class feedXML{
>
> ```
> //Declear Vars
> public $mysongs;
> public $title;
> public $artist;
> public $date;
>
>
> //Load XML file
> public function loadXML(){
>     $this->mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml');
> }
>
> //Assign XML data to Vars
> public function setXMLdata(){
>
>     foreach($this->mysongs as $songinfo){
>
>         $this->title=$songinfo->title;
>         $this->artist=$songinfo->artist;
>         $this->date=$songinfo['dateplayed'];
>
>     }//end foreach
> }
>
> //Return Title element
> public function getTitle(){
>     echo $this->title;
> }
> //Return Artist element
> public function getArtist(){
>     echo $this->artist;
> }
> //Return Date element
> public function getDate(){
>     echo $this->date;
> } }
> ```
>
> $test = new feedXML(); $test->getDate();

XML file structure:

songs
song - title - artist - song 
song - title - artist - song
song - title - artist - song
songs

I am trying to echo out the variables but nothing appear on the browser..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you gave never reads or interacts with the XML file, therefore `$date` is never set. You need to call your `loadXML` and `setXMLdata` functions.